# How to fetch matching key values from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dictionary

I have an object with the following data:

```
obj =
{
  key: 'mykey1597855209',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JW=='
}
{
  key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
}
{
  key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='
}
{
  key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='
}
```

When I do `console.log(typeof obj)` , I get `object` as output

I want to store only unique `integrity` values in an array for the keys which have `mykey*` in the `key value`

> Desired Output:

```
[ 'sha512-T9JWj==', 'sha512-lcddfd==' ]
```

> Code:

```
var output = [];

for (var key in obj) {
  if(obj[key] === 'mykey') {
    output.push(obj[integrity])
  }
}

console.log(output.join(', '))
```

Comment: you can use regex to match with pattern rather than ===.

Comment: okay. also how to get only unique `integrity` value?

Comment: for unique integrity, create a dictionary. Here dictionary key will be integrity.
const dict = { }
for(var key in obj) {
   dict[key[integrity]] =  key
}

Comment: You mention in a comment on an answer that `obj` is not an array. You are correct. It is not an array. Nor is it "JSON" or a "JSON Object" (JSON always has been and always will be a string). `obj` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first `filter` the array to obtain only objects with a matching key value, `map` each resulting element to its `integrity` property, create a `Set` from that array, and finally use spread syntax to obtain the result as an array.

```js
const arr = [
{
  key: 'mykey1597855209',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
},
{
  key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
},
{
  key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='
},
{
  key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='
}];
const res = [...new Set(arr.filter(({key})=>/mykey/.test(key)).map(({integrity})=>integrity))];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: please note that `obj` is not an `array`

Comment: Please provide some valid sample data then.